# Entity Framework naming queries

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, azure, sql-server-profiler

We're analyzing Azure "Query Performance Insight" to look for expensive queries, the problem is that, there is no way to relate SQL generated vs Entity Framework query.

Is there any extension method or anything else to do something like this:

SQL generated:

```
-- BlahMethod
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
```

Entity Framework cmd:

```
Context.Table1.Naming("BlahMethod").ToList()
```

Or even better:

```
Context.Table1.ToList() // intercept sql generated by EF and put through reflection the Method and Namespace "MyAssembly.Foo.MyMethodName"
```

SQL Generated:

```
-- MyAssembly.Foo.MyMethodName
SELECT Id
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, look at this article [Logging and Intercepting Database Operations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn469464.aspx).

It can be as simple as using Console.Write:

```
using (var context = new BlogContext()) 
{ 
    context.Database.Log = Console.Write; 

    // Your code here... 
}
```

Or you can use a log class:

```
  using (var db = new MyDBContext())
            {

                db.Database.Log = s => Log.TraceVerbose("DB Context:{0}", s);
...
```

Comment: No, I want to log on sql generated

Comment: This is exact what the log will be. The generated SQL query, Read the link on the post.